# Relation between VendPackingSlipJour and GeneralJournalEntry

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I am working on SSRS Report that show the accrual in AX for purchase order.

When going to purchase>Product Receipt->Voucher, I can't find relation between purchase order line and Voucher. Note that Product receipt in `VendPackingSlipJour` contain `purchId` and `GeneralJournalEntry` contain number of voucher.

Kindly, can anyone help me how I can find the relation between the two tables to get the accrual of purchase order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It goes from `VendPackingSlipJour` -> `VendPackingSlipVersion` -> `SubledgerVoucherGeneralJournalEntry` -> `GeneralJournalEntry`

It seems there may be more than one `VendPackingSlipVersion` record per `VendPackingSlipJour`, then use the `VendPackingSlipVersion.findLatest` method to find the relevant one.

[This paper](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh292603.aspx) may be of help regarding the ledger rubbish in AX 2012.